# blank is a 'variable' but is used like a 'method' - why am I getting this?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I have a list of cleaners (linq class) I am trying to remove 'cleaners if they are unconfirmed. Here is my code.

```
 List<ConfirmCleaner> Unconfirmed = context.ConfirmCleaners.Where(d => d.confirmed == false).ToList();
                List<Cleaner> Cleaners = context.Cleaners.ToList();
                List<Cleaner> TempCleaners = new List<Cleaner>();

                foreach (var c in Unconfirmed)
                {
                    foreach(var r in Cleaners){
                         if(c.cleanerId == r.id){
                             TempCleaners.Add(r);
                         }
                    }


                }
                List<Cleaner> result = Cleaners().Except(TempCleaners()).ToList();
                return result;
```

Why am I getting an error :

> 'Cleaners' is a 'variable' but is used like a 'method'

Comment: In the second to last line, what is `Cleaners()` supposed to do? I think you probably meant `Cleaners.Except(TempCleaners)`.

Comment: It is supposed to return what is in the first list ie. Cleaners, with the exception of what is in the second list ie. TempCleaners

Comment: Ok but the variable is `Cleaners` (note: no parentheses), adding parentheses on the end makes the compiler think it's a method call and it's not.

Comment: What @mikez is trying to hint to you is that you have the identifier `Cleaners`, to which you have added method invocation syntax, i.e. a pair of parens `()`, even though there's no need for them there. And that's exactly what the error message is saying.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```
List<Cleaner> result = Cleaners().Except(TempCleaners()).ToList();
```

You need to change it to:

```
List<Cleaner> result = Cleaners.Except(TempCleaners).ToList();
```

Comment: Thx! I had to take the parentheses off TempCleaners too :)

Answer (score 1):

Hope that the error message is clear enough to identify the issue, anyway you have declared  `Cleaners` as a List of `Cleaner`, and When you were using that variable  in the final query you are using the same like `Cleaners().` When you use like this, the compiler expects a method, and that is what the compiler specified in the error message as well. So the code should be :

```
 return Cleaners.Except(TempCleaners()).ToList();
```